# Setting proxy port, why cannot I use another port except 9000?

Tags: nginx, lighttpd, proxypass

I need web server and try Nginx and Lighttpd. I try to set proxy path and can use both. But it doesn't works if I use port 8080, 9001, 19000 ... It works well only under port 9000. It is same both case of Nginx and Lighttpd.

My environment
host OS: Windows 10
VirtualBox 5.2
guest OS: CentOS 7

```
Nginx
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }  


Lighttpd
    proxy.server = ("/" => ((
        "host" => "127.0.0.1",
        "port" => 9000,
    )))
```

Need I set OS environment?
Why does it work only in case of port 9000?

### The mean of "work well" is like next.

Server is coded in socket of C language.

I enter 192.168.0.111 in Chrome to connect to server. After accepting, server receive message from socket_fd and send message to socket_fd.

```
recv(socket_fd, buf, 3999, 0);
send(socket_fd, "TTT === TTT", strlen("TTT === TTT"), 0);
```

Message from client is followings

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:9000
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: TRACKID=c9130c835a38d41a826a34a5939cf8c5
```

Message from server is followings.

```
TTT === TTT
```

This message is displayed in Chrome.

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does it mean "works well", how you recognize it?

Comment: @Alex C Thank you your attention. I must have written in detail. I'm sorry.